# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 with FIND_IN_SET

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is my query:

```
    $ids = Profile::select('user_id')->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, favorites)', [$course])->get();
```

A var_dump of $course give int(133)
and if I try to add 133 instead of $course the query works:

```
    $ids = Profile::select('user_id')->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, favorites)', [133])->get();
```

but I need to use $course var in the query without general error. 
How?

UPDATE (error)

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 
(SQL: select `user_id` from `profiles` where FIND_IN_SET(?, favorites))"
```

Comment: did you try to print $course value and check type of $course variable?

Comment: yes, is INTEGER

Comment: in you first query you use "favorites" and in you second query you use "favoriti"

Comment: can you please add which error has been occurred when you user $course variable to your question?

Comment: Done, I've added the error.

Comment: try without square bracket

Comment: Same error also without square bracket.

Comment: sorry, i gave all the related solutions, now without doing debugging i can not help you. Because this issue need some real time debugging with Database and data

Comment: What's the result of `dd($course);`?